# Autofac - Wire up property based on name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have an interface IRepository, which is my DB repository.

Lets say I have a class UserService

```
public class UserService
{
       IRepository ScopedReop {get; set;}
       IRepository Repo {get; set;}
}
```

How can I wire up these two properties based on name using Autofac?

Thanks

Paul